# What sorting alogrithm is used by mongodb's sort and nested array sort?

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting, database-performance

I am experimenting with MongoDB's `sort` performance to decide whether or not to store a user's location history `{ts: DATE(), location: "loc"}` (maxHistorySize=100) within the user object or in a separate collection.

My goal is to achieve better TPS. It's expected to have a lot more writes than reads.

The major concern I have right now is the performance of sorting (which I will need for querying and housekeeping, also while inserting(create index)).

**When stored within**, the write query would be something like this. 
My concern is how quickly it can finish the sort.
Since the `$sort` run every time an insertion takes place, the array would be largely sorted already.
I am wonder whether the `sort` has a runtime of `O(log(n))` or `O(nlog(n))`

```
        update: {
          $setOnInsert: {userId: 'userId'},
          $push: {
            locations: {
              $each: [{location: 'location', ts: new Date()}],
              $slice: -100,
              $sort: {ts: 1}
            }
          },
```

**When stored separately**, I would have to create an index on `ts`. Since MongoDB uses `B-tree` to create an index, I am guessing the overhead is just O(log(n)). The drawback is that it uses extra spaces.

I am not sure where, to begin with, any recommendations is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB uses [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) (called from [sortChildren](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/bson/mutable/algorithm.h#L121-L149) called from [PushNode::performPush](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/update/push_node.cpp#L301-L304).

I believe std::sort is O(nlog(n)).